# Dynamically retrieve class information in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, class, static

So the question is fairly simple but I'm not sure how to word it in order to find the answer.

I'm trying to access a class i.e. `[MyCustomClass]` in order to check static properties but I need to do it dynamically. How do I inject the class name like `[$className]`?

Or are there any cmdlets or .NET class functions I can use for this purpose? I tried searching `Get-Command *Class*` and some similar commands but am not coming up with anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 primary options for resolving a given type by name, each with slightly different behavior:

1. Using a cast to `[type]`:

```
$className = 'MyCustomClass'
$myType = [type]$className
```

Attempting to cast a non-existing type name will throw an exception:

```
PS ~> [type]'Not actually a type'
Cannot convert the "Not actually a type" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
At line:1 char:1
+ [type]'Not actually a type'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToType
```

2. Using the `-as` type conversion operator (introduced in PowerShell version 3.0):

```
$myType = 'MyCustomClass' -as [type]
```

Unlike casting, the `-as` operator *never* throws - it simply returns `$null`:

```
PS ~> $myType = 'this does not exist' -as [type]
PS ~> $null -eq $myType
True
```

Common for both of these is that you can now resolve the static members of `[MyCucstomClass]`:

```
$myType::MyProperty
```

---

The static member operator `::` also works on *instance* references, so if you have an object of type `[MyCustomClass]`, use that in place of a type literal:

```
class MyClass
{
  static [string] $StaticValue = 'Static string value'
}
```

```
PS ~> $instance = [MyClass]::new()
PS ~> $instance::StaticValue
Static string value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Invoke-Expression` to run something you still have to build:

```
$class = 'DateTime'
Invoke-Expression "[$class]::Now"
```

Comment: The obligator warning; this is a classic example of better alternatives being available: `Invoke-Expression`  (`iex`) should generally be _avoided_ and used only as a _last resort_, due to its inherent security risks. In short: Avoid it, if possible, given that superior alternatives are usually available. If there truly is no alternative, only ever use it on input you either provided yourself or fully trust - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375).

Comment: This should probably come with a warning about passing untrusted input to `Invoke-Expression` :-)

Comment: Both these comments are absolutely true - use mr. Jenssen's answer in any real use case.